# Can we validate a number in json with quotes as invalid?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON body, which contains number, string, Boolean and array values.

```
{
    "name": "vivek",
    "age": 12,
    "employed": true,
    "cars": ["maruti", "wagonR"]
}
```

The only acceptable case should be `{"age":12}` for age.
In all other case it should request to re-enter the age.(i.e. `{"age":"12"}`) 
What are the possible ways to validate this?

Comment: I'd check the type of the value using unary `typeof` after parsing the JSON.

Comment: Decode the JSON into an object, check the ***type*** of the value, throw whatever errors you want…?!

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the JSON and check the type of its property 'age', or if it exists. There're other ways too, but by checking the type is safer since age can be any value, and getting its constructor property might result in an exception.

```
var json = JSON.parse('JSON CONTENTS');

// Fast way to check whether getters operations can
// be done at json.
if (json) {
    var age = json.age;

    if (json.hasOwnProperty('age')) {
        var type = typeof age;
        if (type !== 'number')
            throw new Error('age cannot be a ' + type);
    } else {
        throw new Error('age is required');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just had to stringify the JSON before parsing it.

Comment: @user2745101 Hey, but you don't need to stringify/parse it – if it's already accessible for you

Comment: JSON is not accessible to me directly. it is coming in request in APIGEE

Comment: @user2745101 Is it coming as string? Then you don't need to stringify it (shouldn't). If it's coming as object, it should be your JSON object parsed (although JSON can be composed of any kind of value).